# Bitcoin-Qt does not unpack the bootstrap.dat

Tags: bitcoind, bootstrap.dat, raspberry-pi

I downloaded a copy of the `bootstrap.dat` for a node I'm trying to set up on a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian OS, based on Debian). I placed it in `./bitcoin`, which is the right place according to what I read. 
Still, when I open `Bitcoin-Qt it acts likes there's nothing there and starts synchronizing the chain from scratch. 
Am I missing something?